# Sending a DELETE request to django-rest with angular is interpreted as OPTIONS

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-cors-headers

i try to consume a rest API built with django-rest with angularjs but i've a problem.
When i send a DELETE request, django-rest see OPTIONS.

this is what i did :

My Django views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def node_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a node. 
    """
    try:
        node = Node.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Node.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = NodeSerializer(node)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = NodeSerializer(node, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        node.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I've added CORS with django-cors-headers and all Origins are accepted (CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True)

I've an angular service to manage this with $resource

```
angular.module('akilio.nodes.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('NodeServices', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/nodes/:nodeId/', {nodeId: '@nodeId'});
});
```

Now, with a button where ng-click="deleteNode()", i call this controller

```
controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'NodeServices', function($scope, $routeParams, NodeServices) {
        $scope.node = NodeServices.get({nodeId: $routeParams.pk});

        $scope.deleteNode = function(){
            $scope.node.$delete(function(){
                console.log('ok');
            }, function(){
                console.log('nok');
            });
        };
    }]);
```

console.log() returns me "nok" each time, and in my django console, i see

```
[08/Nov/2013 09:39:10] "OPTIONS /nodes HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

FYi, my angular version is v1.2.0-rc.3 then i've added to my app

```
config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
     $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'http://127.0.0.1']);
 }])
```

but nothing changed :(

An idea ?

**EDIT**

i think the problem comes from $resource, maybe i'm wrong in the implementation.
I've tried to delete a node with $http instead of $resource like

```
$http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/nodes/4/');
```

and everything is ok.

Comment: Does it work, when you call PUT witch the same settings?

Comment: Nope, same behavior :(

Comment: I posted an answer, not sure if that will get it done, so you need to try play around with these settings.. btw. why using CORS? is the client on a different domain or smth?

Comment: thanks for your help buy nothing has changed :(. I used CORS because my django serve on localhost:8000 dans my angular app on localhost:8888. In the futur it's an API which may becomes public then i need CORS

Comment: If the client is on :8888 then try to change `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` accordingly. Have you done that? I remember I had the same problem a while ago and these settings helped, so maybe try to play around, remove some parts and see what happens.. Also can you update your post with exact headers that has been send with the request? So we have some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact the problem comes from Django which add a trialing space.
Then when angular tries to get `http://test/url` but django redirect it to `http://test/url/`
This redirect imply data loosing.

My solution was to [this modification](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/69be39fccfceae13c4850e1dcf097fcd7d9ce395/src/ngResource/resource.js#L329) into resource.js file.

Other solutions are possible, Django side with APPEND_SLASH as False

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust your django settings accordingly:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('127.0.0.1:8000', )

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1'
```

also, if you use csrf token, then don't forget this:

```
app.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $.cookie('csrftoken');
});
```